# Type aliasing structures that meet an interface requirement

Tags: go

See code below:

I have an odd behavior that I can't understand in Go. If I want to create a type alias of a structure and that structure meets the requirements of a interface type, then the type alias won't meet the requirements of that interface type. I have no idea why this is happening. Any thoughts?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyInt struct {
    value int
}

func (m MyInt) DoubleIt() int {
    return m.value * 2
}

type MyInter interface {
    DoubleIt() int
}

type MyIntContainer struct {
    d MyInter
}

type MC MyIntContainer
type MI MyInt

func main() {
    e1 := MyIntContainer{MyInt{12}} //This is OK
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", e1.d.DoubleIt())
    e2 := MC{MI{12}} //this fails with error - line 29
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", e2.d.DoubleIt())
}
```

The error message:

```
Line 29: cannot use MI literal (type MI) as type MyInter in field value:
MI does not implement MyInter (missing DoubleIt method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code `MI` is a new type which doesn't carry over the methods from the original type. The `DoubleIt` method really isn't available:

```
e2 := MI{12}
fmt.Printf("%d\n", e2.DoubleIt())
```

> ```
> e2.DoubleIt undefined (type MI has no field or method DoubleIt)
> ```

An alternative if you want to carry over the methods would be to embed `MyInt`:

```
type MI struct {
    MyInt
}
```

Then you can say:

```
e2 := MI{MyInt{12}}
fmt.Printf("%d\n", e2.DoubleIt())
```

---

From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types):

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of any
>   **other type T** consists of all methods **declared with receiver type T**. Further rules apply to structs containing anonymous fields, as
>   described in the section on struct types. **Any other type has an empty
>   method set**.